# Optimize the Query in PostgreSQL - Takes too long

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

Made this view to see all the 'socios' turned their status_contrato to 301 in the last 30 days
The thing is the query takes around 30 secs, and I have to get down to 20 secs max

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.socios_desligados_inadimplencis_ultimos_30_dias_v2
AS SELECT tb.nome,
    tb.cpf,
    tb.email,
    tb.plano,
    tb.status_contrato,
        CASE
            WHEN ad.dt_inicial IS NULL THEN tb.dt_inicial
            ELSE ad.dt_inicial
        END AS data_admissao,
    tb.dthr_desligamento,
    tb.total_parcelas_pagas
   FROM ( SELECT p.idpessoa,
            p.nome,
            p.cpf,
            p.email,
            pl.dscplano AS plano,
            ea.dscestado_ativacao AS status_contrato,
            eal.ins_dthr AS dthr_desligamento,
            cr.valor_total AS total_parcelas_pagas,
            con.dt_inicial
           FROM base_pessoa p
             JOIN ( SELECT gs_contrato.idpessoa,
                    gs_contrato.idcontrato,
                    gs_contrato.idplano,
                    gs_contrato.idestado_ativacao,
                    gs_contrato.dt_inicial
                   FROM gs_contrato
                  WHERE gs_contrato.idestado_ativacao::text = '301'::text AND gs_contrato.alt_dthr >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30)) con ON p.idpessoa::text = con.idpessoa::text
             JOIN gs_plano pl ON con.idplano::text = pl.idplano::text
             JOIN gs_estado_ativacao ea ON con.idestado_ativacao::text = ea.idestado_ativacao::text
             JOIN ( SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY lg.idcontrato ORDER BY lg.ins_dthr DESC) AS linha,
                    lg.idcontrato,
                    lg.idestado_ativacao,
                    lg.ins_dthr
                   FROM gs_estado_ativacao_l lg
                     JOIN gs_contrato con_1 ON con_1.idcontrato::text = lg.idcontrato::text
                  WHERE lg.idestado_ativacao::text = '301'::text AND con_1.idestado_ativacao::text = '301'::text AND con_1.alt_dthr >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30) AND lg.ins_dthr >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30)) eal ON con.idcontrato::text = eal.idcontrato::text AND eal.linha = 1
             JOIN ( SELECT ccr.idcontrato,
                    sum(ccr.valor - ccr.valor_desconto + ccr.valor_juros + ccr.valor_multa + ccr.valor_adesao + ccr.valor_acrescimo) AS valor_total
                   FROM cx_conta_receber ccr
                     JOIN gs_contrato c ON c.idcontrato::text = ccr.idcontrato::text
                  WHERE ccr.status::text = 'PA'::text AND c.idestado_ativacao::text = '301'::text AND c.alt_dthr >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30)
                  GROUP BY ccr.idcontrato) cr ON cr.idcontrato::text = con.idcontrato::text) tb
     JOIN data_adesao ad ON tb.idpessoa::text = ad.idpessoa::text;
```

Comment: If you can provide input tables and output, it can be easier to provide some help for me. A high-level suggestion is to avoid too many joins (if you can), to move the join operations as the last ones to carry on and to create indices on the columns you need to filter out.

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query? Without that information we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your query. I write some recommendations for performance.

1. Recommended using materialized CTE (`with as materialized`) instead of subqueries.
2. Maybe you have used subqueries or table-joining to get a few values. You can use return-table functions instead at this.
3. Check your indexes. Fields are used on the conditions (`where` or `join`), on the `order by` or `group by` commands must be indexed.
4. Not recommended use casting fields or set functions to fields in the conditions. In this time DB can not use indexes. If you need set functions to fields in the conditions, then recommended creating `expression index` (`function-based index`).

Your query has some cast types:

```
WHERE gs_contrato.idestado_ativacao::text = '301'::text 
AND gs_contrato.alt_dthr >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30)) con ON 
p.idpessoa::text = con.idpessoa::text
JOIN gs_plano pl 
ON con.idplano::text = pl.idplano::text
JOIN gs_estado_ativacao ea 
ON con.idestado_ativacao::text = ea.idestado_ativacao::text

WHERE lg.idestado_ativacao::text = '301'::text 
AND con_1.idestado_ativacao::text = '301'::text 
AND con_1.alt_dthr >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30) 
AND lg.ins_dthr >= (CURRENT_DATE - 30)) eal ON con.idcontrato::text = eal.idcontrato::text AND eal.linha = 1
```

If you need cast types, so use the same cast types at creating indexes. Expression index.

And the latest and most important recommendation is that use `explain analyze` for this query to get execute plan of DB.